# Is 方 being used as a suffix in this sentence?

Tags: suffixes

I'm fairly certain 方 is being used as a suffix in the following sentence based on three things; as explained below, but I would like a secondary opinion to confirm or deny my claim.

> 実戦では、拳法のような型や構え**方**は意味がない。

1. According to [Tai Kim's guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/comparison#Using_to_express_a_way_to_do_something), 方 is used as a noun and is read in two different ways, かた and ほう. I doubt the 方 is being used as a noun in my sentence, based on my second piece of reasoning.
2. Seeing as 型や構え are two nouns connected by the や particle, 方 can only either be a verb (highly unlikely) or a suffix for the sentence fragment to make syntactical sense in Japanese.
3. In the definition of the かた reading for 方 [here](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%96%B9), the third provided definition "noun, noun - used as suffix translated as 'method of; manner of; way of' has the following example sentence.

   > その少年はカーブの投げ方を知っている。

3.2 Seeing as how 投げ is most likely being used as a noun; and is before the 方; I came to the conclusion my 方 is also being used in the same manner; which appears to be as a suffix.

Comment: 憲法? Isn't it 拳法?

Comment: @Spoonail Thanks for pointing that out. I must be going blind, or my Japanese kanji IME keyboard input the wrong kanji by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this 方 is a suffix, and it's the same as 方 as in 投げ【なげ】方【かた】. 構え【かまえ】方【かた】 means "way of taking a posture". Although 構え can be used as a noun on its own, here it's used as a verb, forming a noun *in combination with* 方. That is, it's parsed like `(型)や(構え方)`, not `(型や構え)方`.

By the way, what's the difference between 型 and 構え方? 型 ("form") includes moves of martial arts (e.g., how to punch, kick or throw), whereas 構え方 is only about taking a good posture.